# Label along the line in Flex LineChart

Tags: apache-flex, flash, flex3, charts

I'd like to put a label to each LineSeries on my Flex LineChart so it will be shown next to the line (along it). Any relatively easy way to archieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Well what Mike is asking is quite reasonable, as for the colorblind people Legend might not work well, so they need a strong visual indication that, which line is representing which series.

Can't think of anything else though... :(

Comment: There are some special types of graphs where labels must be like that.

Comment: Yes - railway companies use train charts where X axis is time, Y axis are stations, and lines are trains. They need to have train numbers next to the lines. See an example here: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/ru/thumb/5/5a/PrimerGDP2.JPG/600px-PrimerGDP2.JPG (in Russian)

Answer (score 0):

How is your question different from this example: [LineChart and AreaChart controls example](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/charts/series/LineSeries.html) (scroll to the bottom)?

Comment: It is different as I want labels displayed on the series, not as a separate legend. This is important for me as my chart has about 30 to 50 series, and differentiating them by color makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find that what you are asking will clutter your chart.

Perhaps instead, you add a mouseover event handler to each legend item and when the event fires, highlight the series in one way or another.

When I did this, I simply faded all series except for the one selected.

Comment: Well that's a requirement unfortunately. The layout and look'n'feel of this specific chart is defined by corporate standards that my customer cannot and not willing to control. The mouseover things is implemented already, but it is not enough for instance because I need to print that chart nicely.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `CartesianDataCanvas` to position your labels.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=charts_eventsandeffects_13.html